# How to ignore Empty Values during XMLSerilization in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, xml-serialization

I am fetching Data from the DB. If the DBObject data has empty value `("")` not null then I want to exculde that value from the XML Serilization.

```
  EventComment event = new EventComment();
        event.Comments = datalogic.GetComment();

    if(event.Comments != String.Empty){
    //Add Logic
    }
SerializeToXmL(event)
    //dataLogic Class
        public string GetComment()
                {
                    var datalink = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<tbl1>()
                                 .GetFirstOrDefault(predicate: source => (source.id == id));
        
        
                    return datalink .comment;
                }
```

I know we can use null value but i do not want to assign null value to the variable. Can I get diffrent solution from null. I am getting empty tag as of now after XML serilization.

```
<comment/>
```

Comment: what is the thing that you are serializing? and is it `null`, or is it empty (`""`) ?

Comment: I am serilizaling  ( " ").

Answer (score 1):

`null` values are already excluded; if we're talking about ignoring empty strings (`""`), then "conditional serialization" is your friend. Many serializers (including `XmlSerializer`) support this via a well-known `public bool ShouldSerialize*()` pattern, for example:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    [XmlElement("comment")]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeComment() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Comment);
}
```

If I serialize this with an empty `Comment`: the `Comment` member is not serialized. You can trivially extend this to apply any other logic you like, for example:

```cs
public bool ShouldSerializeComment() => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Comment);
```